# How to build a docker container for a synchronized source code?

Tags: git, docker, gruntjs, bower, dockerfile

I want to build a container for nodejs-bower-grunt but keeping my source code synchronized with the git repository (Bitbucket in this case). The idea is to provide a container to my team so that each one of the developers does not need to install these bunch of packages in their environments. Instead of installing nodejs, bower and grunt to run the front end of the app, they just use a container to manage them and focus on the source code. So this is my DockerFile:

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core
RUN     ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app/
ADD bower.json .bowerrc* /app/

RUN     npm install -g bower 
RUN     npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN     npm install 
RUN     bower install --allow-root

CMD ["grunt", "serve"]

EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 35729
```

So I build the container and then run using this code:

```
docker run -ti -p 9000:9000 -p 35729:35729 -d -v /home/MY_USER/Projects/app:/app --name app --net=host my_repository/app
```

expecting that the VOLUME parameter would inject the source code into /app folder in the container without replacing all the stuffs previously configured in the DockerFile. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), the contents were supposed to be kept:
"*the /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content*", but it turns out that when I check the running container, the contents mounted by the DockerFile are replaced by the -v folder contents passed by parameter. One solution would be copy all the app contents to the container itself and then run the container but this solution would be impractical for a developing project, as every update in the app would require building another container. So, my question is: How can I build this container in such a way that every update in the host source code would reflect the running container ?

Comment: The documentation tells: the mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. The second part is also important. Your pre-existing content is not accessible during the mount. I don't know if its possible (don't know the application) but a solution could be to change your folder/app structure. E.G a folder project with in it your package.json and bower.json ADD) + inside the project folder a folder with app to where your mounting the app. But don't know if it's possible in your case.

Comment: it is already this way. The files package.json and bower.json are located in the root folder of the app, and the app folder also in the root contains all other app files.

Comment: It's not very clear for me. So package.json and bower.json are in /app and your application is actually in /app/app/* or what do you mean? when your application is also in /app than it will overlay your package.json and bower.json

Comment: the folder of the docker commands are the same: /app. This is because you need to run these commands to build the bower and node dependencies. But I am assuming that the -v parameter (path) is overwriting the structure built by the Dockerfile, which should have built dependencies inside the same path

Comment: It is indeed. Although not really overwriting because when you unmount your volume you will see your package.json + bower.json back in it.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a solution, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099387/how-can-you-get-grunt-livereload-to-work-inside-docker) post. The right way to run the container should be like:

```
docker run -ti -p 9000:9000 -p 35729:35729 -d -v /home/MY_USER/Projects/app/app:/app/app --name app --net=host my_repository/app
```

This command tells docker to initialize the container and mount a volume at only the app sub folder instead of the entire root structure of the application, this way keeping all the bunch of configuration made during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would have to pull the changes to the container(s) individually  from the repository of the main current image. Or, you could use something like rsync to sync live file changes between local docker container and then push that to the source code.

Comment: I still want to see how other developers dealt with these issues in a viable way...

Comment: Ok, I think I misread your question or am not understanding it thoroughly